# python module to remove internet jargon/slang/acronym

Tags: python, nlp, acronym

Is there any python module (may be in nltk python) to remove internet slang/ chat slang like "lol","brb" etc. If not can some one provide me a CSV file comprising of such vast list of slang?

The website http://www.netlingo.com/acronyms.php gives the list of acronyms but I am not able to find any CSV files for using them in my program.

Comment: Thanks for that tip on acceptance I was not paying attention to it until now. About my question, I have used beautiful soup for parsing xml content, but now I am just looking for the list of acronyms does beautiful soup have one such module containing such list/dictionary of acronyms? I doubt it.

Comment: You misunderstood me: you should use BS to turn the HTML page on the linked site into a CVS file. :)

Comment: You might also want to check out the `acronyms` file that comes with the `wtf` utility in some Unix distributions.  I found one version online: http://svn.dslinux.org/viewvc/dslinux/branches/bsdgames_branch/user/games/bsdgames/wtf/acronyms?revision=565&view=markup&pathrev=565

Comment: Oh that was definitely a worthy acronym file. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The Jargon File: http://www.catb.org/jargon/ .
- [Kevin's Word List Page](http://wordlist.sourceforge.net/): see Links to Slang Word Lists and Dictionaries

Comment: That is definitely a huge collection of Jargons, although filtering out the needed ones is a bit of pain. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

code to scrap http://www.netlingo.com/acronyms.php

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, json
resp = requests.get("http://www.netlingo.com/acronyms.php")
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, "html.parser")
slangdict= {}
key=""
value=""
for div in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'list_box3'}):
    for li in div.findAll('li'):
        for a in li.findAll('a'):
            key =a.text
            value = li.text.split(key)[1]
            slangdict[key]=value

with open('myslang.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(slangdict, f, indent=2)
```